# how to get column Index by column name?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, indexof

I have a datagrid having few columns-

The header of the grid is hyperlink and I am setting its value at runtime as follows-

```
string strQ1 = "<a href='somePage.aspx?ID=1'>gfgytyty<a>";
dtGrid.Columns[0].Header = strq1;

string strQ2 = "<a href='somePage.aspx?ID=2'>yhtryrtuyu<a>";
dtGrid.Columns[1].Header = strq2;

and so on...
```

It is working properly.
Now suppose I want to get index of a perticular column of datatgrid by its name but I am not able to get it.
I tried

```
int  colIndex = dtGrid.Columns.IndexOf(dtGrid.Columns[strQ2]);
```

this should return 1 as columnIndex but it is returning -1,

**Also, dtGrid.Columns[strQ2] giving me the null value.**

what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: wpf datagrid or winforms datagridview?

Comment: Is this - dtGrid.Columns[strQ2] leading to valid DataGridColumn object, please verify, that might be an issue. in your case i can see you are assigning strq2 as header but using strQ2 in the IndexOf call

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Yes you are right!! dtGrid.Columns[strQ2] is giving null. Can you please tell the workaround.

Comment: Are you sure that it's [winforms datagrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx)? That has no `Columns` property. But  a `DataGridViewColumn` has no `Header` but a `HeaderText` property. Maybe you mean wpf [`DataGrid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) which columns have a `Header` property. Please don't mix up all together.

Comment: In your original solution, can you try typecasting dtGrid.Columns[strQ2] to DataGridColumn and check, since what you are using will give an object type, which does the reference comparison in the Equals method

Comment: @MicrosoftDN: my first, now deleted answer wasn't correct: _"DataGridViewColumnCollection.IndexOf delegates to ArrayList.IndexOf which uses Object.Equals to compare objects. In this case you compare DataGridViewColums which does not override Equals meaningfully. For that reason only references are compared."_ That has nothing to do with this issue since OP is searching a column that he has just taken from the same grid, so it's the same reference. Actually the reason for the issue is that the `DataGridViewColumnCollection.Item`-indexer property uses the name of the column not the header-text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use LINQ FirstOrDefault to get the object first and only then use .IndexOf(object) :

```
var targetColumn = dtGrid.Columns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Header == strQ2);
var index = dtGrid.Columns.IndexOf(targetColumn);
```

Comment: what if I wanted to check if `c.Header` contains a value?

Answer (score 8):

Here's another approach using `List.FindIndex`:

```
int index = dtGrid.Columns.ToList().FindIndex(c => c.Header  == strQ2);
```

If it's not the WPF `DataGrid`(which it seems to be due to the `Header` property) but a winforms `DataGridView` that doesn't implement a generic collection type, you need to cast it before you can use LINQ methods:

```
var columnList = dtGrid.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().ToList();
int index = columnList.FindIndex(c => c.HeaderText  == strQ2);
```

Comment: This would be an O(n) solution, instead of that a Linq query will be preferable

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: the accepted approach needs to enumerate the column collection twice. However, since there are not thousand  columns that's not an issue.